# Python Socket Programming: Upload files from Client to Server

Tags: python, sockets, unix, filesystems, virtual-machine

I'm looking to find some assistance in my python socket programming. 
Objective: upload a file from the Client to the Server. My current setup involves two virtual machines, a Server and a Client, where the respective .py files will reside; server.py and client.py . The issues I'm experiencing is, that when I go to choose the upload option, the output reads "File uploading.... File successfully uploaded" But when I look on the server side, the file doesn't exist - nor do I receive an error. The server shows that it received a connection when I send the file to upload. What I have currently is below... Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. 


**Server.py**

```
import config, protocol
import os
from socket import *
import threading
import time
import sys


class server():

    # Constructor: load the server information from config file
    def __init__(self):
        self.port, self.path, self.path2 = config.config().readServerConfig()

    # function to receive file data from client 
    def receiveFile(self, serverSocket, fileName):
        serverSocket.connect()
        serverSocket.send(protocol.prepareMsg(protocol.HEAD_UPLOAD, fileName))
        with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
            print('file incoming...')
            while True:
                print('receiving data...')
                data = serverSocket.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)
        print(fileName + " has been Received!")
        serverSocket.close()


    # Main function of server, start the file sharing service
    def start(self):
        serverPort=self.port
        serverSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
        serverSocket.listen(20)
        print('The server is ready to receive')
        while True:
            connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
            print("**Conn. to ", addr)
            dataRec = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            header,msg= protocol.decodeMsg(dataRec.decode()) # get client's info, parse it to header and content
            # Main logic of the program, send different content to client according to client's requests
            if(header== protocol.HEAD_REQUEST):
                self.listFile(connectionSocket)
            elif(header == protocol.HEAD_DOWNLOAD):
                self.sendFile(connectionSocket, self.path+"/"+msg)
            elif(header == protocol.HEAD_UPLOAD):
                self.receiveFile(connectionSocket, self.path2+"/"+msg)
            else:
                connectionSocket.send(protocol.prepareMsg(protocol.HEAD_ERROR, "Invalid Message"))
            connectionSocket.close()






def main():
    s=server()
    s.start()

main()
```

**Client.py**

```
import config, protocol
from socket import *
import threading
import time
import os
import sys

class client:

    fileList=[] # list to store the file information
    uploadFileList = []

    #Constructor: load client configuration from config file
    def __init__(self):
        self.serverName, self.serverPort, self.clientPort, self.downloadPath, self.uploadPath = config.config().readClientConfig()

    # Function to produce user menu 
    def printMenu(self):
        print("Welcome to simple file sharing system!")
        print("Please select operations from menu")
        print("--------------------------------------")
        print("3. Upload File")
        print("5. Quit")

    # Function to get user selection from the menu
    def getUserSelection(self):       
        ans=0
        # only accept option 1-4
        while ans>5 or ans<1:
            self.printMenu()
            try:
                ans=int(input())
            except:
                ans=0
            if (ans<=5) and (ans>=1):
                return ans
            print("Invalid Option")

    # Build connection to server
    def connect(self):
        serverName = self.serverName
        serverPort = self.serverPort
        clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
        return clientSocket

    def getUploadFileList(self):
        self.uploadFileList = os.listdir(self.uploadPath)

    def printUploadFileList(self):
        count = 0
        for f in self.uploadFileList:
            count += 1
            print('{:<3d}{}'.format(count, f))

    def selectUploadFile(self):
        if (len(self.uploadFileList)==0):
            self.getUploadFileList()
        ans=-1
        while ans<0 or ans>len(self.uploadFileList)+1:
            self.printUploadFileList()
            print("Please select the file you want to upload from the list (enter the number of files):")
            try:
                ans=int(input())
            except:
                ans=-1
            if (ans>0) and (ans<len(self.uploadFileList)+1):
                return self.uploadFileList[ans-1]
            print("Invalid number")

    def uploadFile(self, fileName):
        mySocket=self.connect()
        mySocket.send(protocol.prepareMsg(protocol.HEAD_UPLOAD, fileName))
        f = open(fileName, 'rb')
        l = f.read(1024)  # each time we only send 1024 bytes of data
        while (l):
            print('File uploading...')
            mySocket.sendall(l)
            l = f.read(1024)
        f.close()
        print("File Uploaded Successfully!")


    # Main logic of the client, start the client application
    def start(self):
        opt=0
        while opt!=5:
            opt=self.getUserSelection()
            if opt==3:
                self.uploadFile(self.selectUploadFile())
            else:
                pass


def main():
    c=client()
    c.start()


main()
```

I've defined modules in the protocol file that I have...


**Protocol.py**

```
HEAD_LIST='LST'
HEAD_REQUEST='REQ'
HEAD_DOWNLOAD='DLD'
HEAD_UPLOAD='ULD'
HEAD_FILE='FIL'
HEAD_ERROR='ERR'

# we prepare the message that are sent between server and client as the header + content
def prepareMsg(header, msg):
    return (header+msg).encode()

def prepareFileList(header,fList):
    '''
    function to prepare file list to msg
    '''
    msg=header
    for i in range(len(fList)):
        if (i==len(fList)-1):
            msg+=fList[i]
        else:
            msg+=fList[i]+','
    return msg.encode()

# Decode the received message, the first three letters are used as protocol header
def decodeMsg(msg):
    if (len(msg)<=3):
        return HEAD_ERROR, 'EMPTY MESSAGE'
    else:
        return msg[0:3],msg[3:len(msg)]
```

I've also defined my config file as follows...

**Config.py**

```
class config:
    #define header
    server_port='SERVER_PORT'
    path="PATH"
    path2="PATH2"
    server="SERVER"
    client_port="CLIENT_PORT"
    download="DOWNLOAD"
    upload="UPLOAD"
    serverConfig="server.config"
    clientConfig="client.config"

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def readServerConfig(self):
        try:
            with open(self.serverConfig,'r') as f:
                serPort=0
                sharePath=""
                sharePath2=""
                for l in f:
                    sub=l.strip().split("=")
                    if(sub[0]==self.server_port):
                        serPort=int(sub[1])
                    elif(sub[0]==self.path):
                        sharePath=sub[1]
                    elif (sub[0] == self.path2):
                        sharePath2 = sub[1]


                    else:
                        pass
                return serPort, sharePath, sharePath2
        except:
            print(Exception.message())




    def readClientConfig(self):
        '''
        This function read client configuration file, return four values
        @return: serverName
        @return: serverPort
        @return: clientPort
        @return: downloadPath
        '''
        try:
            with open(self.clientConfig,'r') as f:
                serPort=0
                serName=""
                clientPort=0
                downPath=""
                upPath=""
                for l in f:
                    sub=l.strip().split("=")
                    if(sub[0]==self.server_port):
                        serPort=int(sub[1])
                    elif(sub[0]==self.server):
                        serName=sub[1]
                    elif(sub[0]==self.client_port):
                        clientPort=sub[1]   
                    elif(sub[0]==self.download):
                        downPath=sub[1]
                    elif(sub[0]==self.upload):
                        upPath=sub[1]
                    else:
                        pass  
                return serName, serPort, clientPort, downPath, upPath
        except:
            print(Exception.message())

# The function to test the configuration class           
def test():
    conf=config()
    client=conf.readClientConfig()
    server=conf.readServerConfig()
    print(client)
    print(server)
```

The above code will return a file list, I can choose which file I'd like to upload, and the code will state its complete but I cannot find the files on the server. I have test files set up in directories paths on both machines. in addition, my server.config and client.config files are set up as:
**server.config**

```
SERVER_PORT=12007
PATH=/root/serverFiles
PATH2=/root/files
```

**client.config**

```
SERVER=192.168.10.1
SERVER_PORT=12007
CLIENT_PORT=12006
DOWNLOAD=/root/Downloads
UPLOAD=/root/Upload
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uploadFile()` method will `connect()` to the server and then `sendall()` the file content (in 1024 byte chunks).

Your server, on the other hand, will receive the first 1024 bytes (i.e. the first 1024 bytes of *file* *content*), and interpret it according to the protocol, looking at the first three bytes **of** **the** **file** **content**. The client, however, never sends `protocol.HEAD_UPLOAD` as the server expects.

(BTW, I would really recommend you [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the code, and refrain from `*` imports. It makes the code much easier to read, and thus to help.)

Comment: Thanks!, that helped. Explains why the server wouldn't respond. Unfortunately, I'm getting different errors, but all that means is that i'm making progress.

Comment: right now after I make the suggested edits, I see that the file upload is now working successfully - but after the file uploads, the server throws an error:"  socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer  "   I'm trying to research the error now. What I've found is that this is the equivalent to EOF

Comment: At the end of `uploadFile()`, the client socket goes out of scope and is disposed of. The TCP connection is properly closed, informing the server side (the client sending the server a `FIN`ish message). That causes the server-side "connection reset by peer" message. To fix this properly, you need to do two things: a) think about the lifecycle of the client-side connection, and b) the server must be prepared for disconnecting clients, anyway.